# How to insert C++ variable into TCL script program?

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

In NS2, is there any way to embed a C++ variable into the TCL script? For example, in TCL, set routing protocol like this, `set opt(rt) XXX` `XXX` could be a variable which is defined in C++ program, such as

```
if(CONDITION==1) 

     XXX = "FLOODING";

if(CONDITION==2) 

         XXX = "AODV";

...
```

Comment: You're after a way to couple a variable in the two languages? Or are you after doing string manipulations to generate source code? I'll assume the former; the latter is boring…

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [`Tcl_LinkVar`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/LinkVar.htm) to couple the char* variable  in C++ (std::string not supported) to Tcl. Like that, all you have to do is change the C++ variable and call `Tcl_UpdateLinkedVar` to allow Tcl to notice that the variable has changed. You do not need to use `Tcl_UpdateLinkedVar` if you never have any traces set on the variable, but they're actually quite a common mechanism so doing the call is advised. Be aware that `Tcl_UpdateLinkedVar` *is* a reentrant call to the Tcl interpreter; some care should be taken to ensure that any traces you run do not trigger a loop back into your code…

```c++
// Setup (done once)...
Tcl_LinkVar(interp, "XXX", &XXX, TCL_LINK_STRING|TCL_LINK_READ_ONLY);


// Your code ...
if(CONDITION==1) 
     XXX = "FLOODING";
if(CONDITION==2) 
     XXX = "AODV";
// Notify Tcl ...
Tcl_UpdateLinkedVar(interp, "XXX");
```

If you want the setting of the Tcl variable `XXX` to change the C++ variable `XXX`, you need to take extra care. Drop the use of the TCL_LINK_READ_ONLY *and **ensure** that you always use `ckalloc` to allocate memory for the strings in `XXX`* (because Tcl will use the matched `ckfree` to dispose of the old one when setting the C++ variable).